# How can I show the entire file during a pull request without any collapsed sections?

Tags: github

When I check a pull request Github some parts of the modified files are partially collapsed by default. In my opinion this is very annoying, because

1. I must expand them manually to see the entire file
2. I'm used to see the entire file as in Azure Devops.

Is there any setting that to expand all files by default on Github?